# Is it possible to save the kendo chart as png format without using any 3rd party tool (linkspace)?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

In my project have requirement to export chart into png format.Is it possible in kendo-ui with out using ink-space(3rd party tool)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you know how to convert SVG to PNG (the Kendo Chart doesn't provide this out of the box). [Inksape](http://inkscape.org) is an open source tool which can convert SVG to various formats. However you must not use it for some reason you can check this .NET SVG rendering library: http://svg.codeplex.com

Comment: sorry we don't have idea about convert SVG to PNG.Can you please help us?

Comment: I said that in my reply - either use inkskape or try the svg .net library from the link.

Comment: Actually my doubt is how the chart convert into SVG?

Comment: Check the chart API documentation. Look for the sag() method: http://docs.kendoui.com/documentation/api/dataviz/chart

Comment: I think that there is a typo error in @AtanasKorchev answer and he meant `svg()` instead of `sag()`.

Comment: Yes. `svg()` is the method. Seems stackoverflow converts it to sag() if it is not put in a code block.