# When I am exporting Image from Kendo Chart, Only data on x and Y axis is getting exported and not Columns(bars)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

> When I am exporting image using ExportImage function in KendoUI chart
>   only following data is getting exported :
>   [image]
>
> Of course i need to export the bars or columns as well.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?
According to their demo it does export the bars.
Have a look at: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/export

Comment: The chart is first not loaded in DOM, on button click i get the required data and create the chart after chart render event is completed, i have referenced chart data and used export image function but that showing above output

Answer (score 0):

Without rendering the chart it appears that your best bet is to export as SVG and then convert that to PNG as stated here:
[Is it possible to save the kendo chart as png format without using any 3rd party tool (linkspace)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354186/is-it-possible-to-save-the-kendo-chart-as-png-format-without-using-any-3rd-party)

Comment: thanks for the reply !!! The issue was call has been given to export before rendering of columns is been completed, so some execution delay is added.